# Quartz scheduler is continuously opening and closing database connection

Tags: database, spring, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am using JobStoreTX(JDBC jobstore) jobstore to achieve clustering, but my problem is that scheduler is continuously opening and closing the database connection. at least 10 times in a second.

please let me know what property should i set to get connection from connection pool only. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can increase value for this  **org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval** property **(Default Value : 15000 milliseconds)**. 
This Property will Set the frequency (in milliseconds) at which this instance “checks-in”* with the other instances of the cluster. Affects the quickness of detecting failed instances.

You also can try with other Properties form  [Click here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX.html) .

Answer (score 1):

You can use **SchedulerFactoryBean** to create a Scheduler with certain properties, including a datasource. See [SchedulerFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html).